# ElasticSearch 6 NEST How to Retrieve ONLY the exact Documents that correspond to my Search query exact keywords?

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, search, keyword, nest

I would like my query to retrieve only the exact documents that correspond to my Search query exact keywords?

Here is my search method:

```
       Person SearchPerson(Person person)
       {
       try
         {
          var response = client.Search<Person>(s => s
                  .Query(q =>
                          (q.Term(ff => ff.FullName, person.FullName)));

                  return response.Documents.ToList().FirstOrDefault();
              }
              catch (Exception ex)
             {
                  throw ex;
             }
        }

        public class Person
        {

            public Guid Id { get; set; }

            [Keyword]
            public string FullName { get; set; }
            public decimal TotalSalary { get; set; }
            public List<Position> Positions { get; set; } = new List<Position>();

            public Person()
            {
                Id = Guid.NewGuid();
            }
        }

        public class Position
        {
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public bool IsCurrentPosition { get; set; }
            public int? MonthsWorked { get; set; }
            public bool HasAverageLimitStatistic { get; set; } = false;
            public int AverageMonthLimit { get; set; } = 0;
            public decimal Salary { get; set; }
            public string CompanyName { get; set; }
        }
    }
}
```

I would like to query and to retrieve only the documents that contains the exact keywords/string in the POCO person. 
How do I retrieve only the documents that have the exact string `FullName`?

Ok, find the answer based on Russ advice's below and I am editing this to leave the correct function that solves this post.

Working search method"

This function retrieve that uses `.Value` as suggested by Russ does the job.

```
Person PersonExist(Person person)
{
       try
       {
           var response = client.Search<Person>(s => s
                       .AllIndices()
                       .Query(q => q.Term(c => c
                        .Field(p => p.FullName )
                        .Value(person.FullName)
                        )));

           return response.Documents.ToList().FirstOrDefault();
       }
       catch (Exception ex)
       {
           throw ex;
       }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: The code does not wait for the `refresh_interval` or explicitly request a refresh in between indexing documents and searching for them. Without either, the search request will not search newly indexed documents. Take a look at https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/near-real-time.html which explains the refresh interval.

Comment: Hi Russ, Thanks. I updated my code as I put above and added `client.Refresh(defaultIndexName)` to refresh the index after my ad or update. But the problem is still there. Any other guess

Comment: If I could make a recommendation - the example is rather long and convoluted, which, if you're just starting out with NEST, is going to make it much more difficult to diagnose and debug where an issue might be. I would start out with a simple example that creates an index, indexes one `Person`, refreshes the index, searches for that one `Person`, updates that one `Person`, etc. The `Person` type need only have an `Id` and a single property to update

Comment: To answer your last question, the index is not refreshed after the `client.IndexMany(...)` call. Also, `PersonExist` should use the `Id` of the document and `client.DocumentExists(...)` to check for existence. Instead of the `try/catch` around client calls, set `ThrowExceptions()` on `ConnectionSettings` to throw exceptions from the client call.

Comment: Take a look at https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net-example/tree/5.x-netcore which is a walkthrough for building a search web application with NEST and Elasticsearch

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Nice, I'll give a careful look, seems to be a very good material. Regarding adding the `Id` to `PersonExist` I know it would work, I've tested already. But my doubt is indeed if my Index had billions of records and I needed to find a `Person` by the `FullName` without knowing its `Id` and retrieve it to then update it. That is actually my doubt

Comment: Hey Russ, I was revisiting my code and just found that it had a problem that had nothing to do with my new Search method modified to use `.value` as you suggested. So having added the `.value` solved the problem. Thanks for the help

Comment: Glad to hear you got it sorted :)